# How to hide() element when using keyboard but not the one that is next()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i have a mega menu with dropdowns for which i use toggle() to show/hide. No i need to have option to show/hide it when using a keyboard. I have decided that when you click enter the dropdown will open. And it all works well. The problem i have with hiding the correct element.

My code is below

```
<ul>
  <li class="menuContainer">
       <a class="top active"><span   id="home">Home</span></a>
       <div class="sub" style="display: none">
            <ul>
              <li>mega menu item 1</li>
              <li>mega mneu item 2</li>
              <li>mega menu item 3</li>
             </ul>
       </div>
  </li>
 <li class="menuContainer">
       <a class="top active"><span   id="profile">Profile</span></a>
       <div class="sub" style="display: none">
            <ul>
              <li>mega menu item 1</li>
              <li>mega mneu item 2</li>
              <li>mega menu item 3</li>
             </ul>
       </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

to open this using keyboard i use this script

```
$(window).keyup(function (e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13 && $('li.menuContainer > a.top:focus').length) {
    $div = $(this).next("div.sub");
    $div.show();   
  }     
});
```

Its all working fine except that if i want to close megamenu dropdown for Admin i need to open mega menu for Profile.
What i want is that as soon as you 'tab' on Profile you should close the div.sub and if you click enter you will open correct.
I have tried to use

```
$("li.menuContainer div.sub").not($div).hide();
```

but this not working as it opens and hides same element.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

being and idiot :)

```
else if (code == 9 && $('li.menuContainer > a.top:focus').length) {

    $('div.sub').hide(); 


     }
```

this works